# Magento 2 - After invoice delete programatically can't create new invoice properly

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, order-items

I have used the code

```
if ($order->getInvoiceCollection()->count()) {
    $_invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();

    if ($_invoices) {
        foreach ($_invoices as $invoice) {
            $invoice->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

This is deleting invoice, but invoice button was not reappearing although invoice is deleted.

So, I have go through the database table and turns out `order_items` has `item_invoiced` column, I have used this code to set item invoiced value to 0

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $k => $item) {
    echo $item->getId() . "\n";
    $item->setQtyInvoiced(0);
    $item->save();
}
```

After this code invoice button is appearing, but when I am creating invoice it is setting subtotal to negative like `-1000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, I guess you miss the trick. You have to set order items fields to 0 which are effected by creating invoice. Replace your item `foreach` with this.

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $k => $item) {
        echo $item->getId() . "\n";
        $item->setBaseRowInvoiced(0);
        $item->setRowInvoiced(0);
        $item->setQtyInvoiced(0);
        $item->setDiscountInvoiced(0);
        $item->setBaseDiscountInvoiced(0);
        $item->save();
    }
```

You also have to add some order fields to 0 as well. for this you have to add following code in your script.

```
$order->setTotalPaid(0)
        ->setBaseTotalPaid(0)
        ->setBaseTotalInvoiced(0)
        ->setTotalInvoiced(0)
        ->setBaseSubtotalInvoiced(0)
        ->setSubtotalInvoiced(0)
        ->setBaseShippingInvoiced(0)
        ->setShippingInvoiced(0)
        ->setBaseDiscountInvoiced(0)
        ->setDiscountInvoiced(0);
```

I hope this will help, let me know once you tried my answer

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)